# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Socket.IO

Tags: reactjs, nginx, websocket, socket.io, chat

I'm currently using Socket.IO and React to create a chat, but I can't connect to my server because the connection is being refused. I tried using different IP in CORS ORIGIN (and using ['*']), tried using `newSocket = io('localhost:4444');`, tried using `newSocket = io('my domain with reverse proxy to port 4444');`, the only way it works is using the numerical ip of my vm `newSocket = io('195.XXX.XX4:4444');`.

What can I try next?

My frontend is hosted in port 3000, and the socket in 4444.

React-frontend:

```
let newSocket;

try {
  newSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:4444');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  window.location.reload();
}

setSocket(newSocket);

return () => {
  newSocket.disconnect();
};`
```

Socket.IO code (btw the comments are in pt-br):

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const Chat = require('./models/Chat.js');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require('cors'); // Importe a biblioteca CORS

const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;");
    next();
});

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true,
  },
  debug: true,
});


// Use a biblioteca CORS como middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
}));

mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@yc-cluster.bn5qm0z.mongodb.net/socketio`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB Atlas:', err);
});

const chatRoutes = require('./routes/chatRoutes');
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', chatRoutes);

// SOCKET DE CONEXÃO


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });
  console.log('User connected in socket');
  socket.on('join chat', (id_do_clube) => {
    const { id_club } = id_do_clube;
    const chatRoom = 'chat_' + id_club; 
    socket.join(chatRoom);
    console.log('User connected in chat room: ' + 'chat_' + id_club);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected');
    });

    // SOCKET DE ENVIO DE MENSAGENS
    socket.on('chat message', async (message) => {
      
      // Salvar a mensagem no banco de dados
      const chat = new Chat({
        sender: message.sender,
        message: message.message,
        id_club: message.id_club,
        id_user: message.id_user,
        sender: message.sender,
        sender_image: message.sender_image,
        announcement: message.announcement,
        type: message.type,
        role: message.role,
      });
      try {
        const newChat = await chat.save();
        socket.emit('chat message', newChat);
        io.to(chatRoom).emit('chat message', newChat);
        socket.emit('chat message response', "Mensagem enviada com sucesso");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error saving chat message:', err);
      }
    });

    socket.on('get old messages', async (id_club) => {
      try {
        const oldChats = await Chat.find({ id_club }).sort({ timestamp: 'asc' });
        socket.emit('old messages', oldChats);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error retrieving old messages:', err);
      }
    });

    // SOCKET DE EDIÇÃO DE MENSAGENS
    socket.on('edit message', async (editedMessage) => {
      try {
        const { messageId, newMessage, id_user } = editedMessage;
        const chat = await Chat.findById(messageId);
    
        if (!chat) {
          console.error('Mensagem não encontrada');
        }
    
        if (parseInt(chat.id_user) !== parseInt(id_user)) {
          console.error('Usuário sem permissão de editar a mensagem');
        }
    
        const updatedChat = await Chat.findByIdAndUpdate(
          messageId,
          { message: newMessage, edited: true },
          { new: true }
        );
    
        // Emitir evento para informar que deu certo para o cliente
        socket.emit('message edited response', "Mensagem editada com sucesso");
        
        // Obter as mensagens atualizadas para o chat específico
        const id_club = updatedChat.id_club;
        const updatedMessages = await Chat.find({ id_club }).sort({ timestamp: 'asc' });

        // Emitir evento para atualizar a lista de mensagens para o chat específico
        io.to(chatRoom).emit('updated message list', { id_club, messages: updatedMessages });
        
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error editing message:', err);
      }
    });
    
    // SOCKET DE DELEÇÃO DE MENSAGENS
    socket.on('delete message', async (infos) => {
      try {
        const { messageId, id_user } = infos;
        const chat = await Chat.findById(messageId);
        if (!chat) {
          console.error('Mensagem não encontrada');
          return;
        }

        // Verificar se o usuário que está tentando deletar a mensagem é o mesmo que a enviou
        if (parseInt(chat.id_user) !== parseInt(id_user)) {
          console.error('Usuário sem permissão de deletar a mensagem');
          return;
        }
        
        // Salvar a mensagem antiga antes de excluí-la
        const oldMessage = chat.message;

        // Atualizar a mensagem para "Esta mensagem foi excluída" e marcar como deletada
        chat.message = "Esta mensagem foi excluída";
        chat.deleted = true;
        chat.oldMessage = oldMessage; // Salvar a mensagem antiga em um campo separado, se necessário

        // Salvar as alterações no documento
        await chat.save();
            // Emitir evento para informar que deu certo a atualização da mensagem para o cliente
            socket.emit('message deleted response', "Mensagem excluída com sucesso");

        // Obter as mensagens atualizadas para o chat específico
        const id_club = chat.id_club;
        const updatedMessages = await Chat.find({ id_club }).sort({ timestamp: 'asc' });

        // Emitir evento para atualizar a lista de mensagens para o chat específico
        io.to(chatRoom).emit('updated message list', { id_club, messages: updatedMessages });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error deleting message:', err);
      }
    });
  });
});
  
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: If your backend is serving on 3000, then your front end has to connect to port 3000.  Your front-end is not going to ACCEPT any connections.  It isn't offering any services.  Right?

Comment: my backend (socket.io) is serving on 4444, my frontend (react) is serving on 3000

Comment: srry I forgot to paste the error...
GET http://localhost:4444/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OePwYtS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: No, it's not.  Your front-end code is trying to connect to a local server on port 4444.  Your front-end code is not serving anything (which is right).  Your back-end code is serving on port 3000.  No one is serving port 4444.  Connections like this are ONE WAY -- the client connects to a server.  The server never reaches out to a client.

Comment: ok, could you help me fix this? and why it works if I use newSocket = io('195.XXX.XX4:4444');?
195.XXX.XX4 -> this IP is the same ip of my frontend server and backend. (it is in the same virtual machine).

and why you are saying my backend server is serving in 3000?
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
I set my process.env.PORT to 4444

Comment: You didn't tell us that.  Plus, the `origin` lines in your `cors` structures are all hard-coded to 3000.  They aren't substituting your port number.

Comment: You are creating an `http` server on port 4444, not a socket.io server.

Comment: My `origin` lines in `cors` is hard-coded to 3000 because my frontend server is in 3000, i followed the answer below and created a socket server, but it isnt working yet :/ it keeps refusing my connection at localhost or name domain, only works if I use the numerical ip of the vm

Comment: You simply cannot do it this way.  Your front-end **cannot** be a server.  If this is a chat, then you need multiple clients.  If you try it on your local system, you can't have two apps claim the same port. If you try it remotely, you would need an IP address for the remote browser, and that browser will be behind a firewall.  Front-ends are clients.  Back-ends are servers.

Comment: It was a nginx/route problem, my co-worker solved it and Idk the details of the solution, but its working now, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use io.connect(...) ?
Can you put your frontend import?
Is the code in a useeffect?

From your code I can recommend you these steps:

1. Try to use io from socket.io-client

   ```
   import {io} from "socket.io-client";

   //other code

   let newSocket = io('http://localhost:4444');
   //or let newSocket = io('195.XXX.XX4:4444');

   //other code
   ```
2. You missed the socket.io Server:

   ```
   const { Server } = require("socket.io");
   //other import and code

   const io = new Server(server, {
       cors: {
           origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
           methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
           allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
           credentials: true,
       },
       debug: true,
    });
   ```
3. If you receive allow-origin error, add this to allowedHeaders of cors:

   ```
   allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization','Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*']
   ```
4. Make sure you are not starting on port 3000.

   ```
   const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   ```

Let me know if it works. If not, give me more info for my questions.

Comment: sure, srry for the lack of information, the code have more than 2k lines
`import io from "socket.io-client";
that part of the code isnt in a useeffect but im using useeffect to update the chat.
I didn't find it necessary to put more information, as I thought it was not related to my connection refused error
But feel free to ask, this code is part of my job and all the devs already tried to solve it (for at least 5 days and cant make it work yet)

Comment: additional info:
we have a backend for api calls (everything that needs a bd like user info payment etc. ) in port 3333 in a docker container
the socket.io is in 4444
and the frontend in 3000

The issue arises from my inability to use let newSocket = io('195.XXX.XX4:4444'); due to the necessity of an HTTPS route. This is because our backend operates over HTTPS, and failure to utilize it for the socket connection results in a CORS error.

Comment: Trying to set up the Socket.IO server that I missed just now (I'll keep you informed about the outcome).

Comment: any update for server?

Comment: nope, did what you said but it keeps refusing my connection at localhost or name domain, only works if I use the numerical ip of the vm, if you want and have some free time maybe we can join a meet call so I can explain more

Comment: Can you try to use in the cors —> origin: ‘*’

Comment: It was a nginx/route problem, my co-worker solved it and Idk the details of the solution, but its working now, thanks for answering.